# How to convert a binary tree in to a dictionary of levels

Tags: python, tree, binary-tree, breadth-first-search, adjacency-list

In python and any other language it is quite easy to to traverse (in level order so BFS)  a binary tree using a queue data structure. Given an adjecency list representation in python and the root of a tree I can traverse the tree in level order and print level elements in order. Nonetheless what I cannot do is go from an adjecency list representation to a level_dictionary or something of the likes:

so for example I would like to go from

`adjecency_list = {'A': {'B','C'}, 'C':{'D'}, 'B': {'E'}}`

to

`levels = {0: ['A'], 1: ['B','C'], 2: ['D','E']}`

So far I have the following:

```py
q = Queue()
o = OrderedDict()
root = find_root(adjencency_list) # Seperate function it works fine
height = find_height(root, adjencency_list) # Again works fine
q.put(root)

# Creating a level ordered adjecency list
# using a queue to keep track of pointers
while(not q.empty()):
    current = q.get()
    try:
        if(current in adjencency_list):
            q.put(list(adjencency_list[current])[0])
            # Creating ad_list in level order
            if current in o:
                o[current].append(list(adjencency_list[current])[0])
            else:
                o[current] = [list(adjencency_list[current])[0]]
        if(current in adjencency_list):
            q.put(list(adjencency_list[current])[1])
            # Creating ad_list in level order
            if current in o:
                o[current].append(list(adjencency_list[current])[1])
            else:
                o[current] = [list(adjencency_list[current])[1]]
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

All it does is place the adjecency list in the the correct level orders for the tree and if I printed a the start of the loop it would print in level order traversal. Nonetheless it does not solve my problem. I am aware adjecency list is not the best representation for a tree but I require using it for the task I am doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recursive way to create the level dictionary from your adjacency list would be -

```
def level_dict(adj_list,curr_elems,order=0):
    if not curr_elems:    # This check ensures that for empty `curr_elems` list we return empty dictionary
            return {}   
    d = {}
    new_elems = []
    for elem in curr_elems:
            d.setdefault(order,[]).append(elem)
            new_elems.extend(adj_list.get(elem,[]))
    d.update(level_dict(adj_list,new_elems,order+1))
    return d
```

The starting input to the method would be the root element in a list, example - `['A']` , and the initial level, which would be 0.

In each level, it takes the chlidren of the elements at that level and creates a new list, and at the same time, creates the level dictionary (in `d`) .

---

Example/Demo -

```
>>> adjecency_list = {'A': {'B','C'}, 'C':{'D'}, 'B': {'E'}}
>>> def level_dict(adj_list,curr_elems,order=0):
...     if not curr_elems:
...             return {}
...     d = {}
...     new_elems = []
...     for elem in curr_elems:
...             d.setdefault(order,[]).append(elem)
...             new_elems.extend(adj_list.get(elem,[]))
...     d.update(level_dict(adj_list,new_elems,order+1))
...     return d
...
>>> level_dict(adjecency_list,['A'])
{0: ['A'], 1: ['C', 'B'], 2: ['D', 'E']}
```